# Fractional day of the year computation in C++14

Tags: c++, date, datetime, time, c++-chrono

I wrote the following code using Howard Hinnants `date.h` library, to compute the fractional day of the year of the current time. I was wondering if there are shorter ways of doing it, because my code feels like an overkill of `std::chrono` and `date` calls. Can I directly calculate the number of fractional days since the start of the year (at microsecond precision) and avoid my two-step approach?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include "date.h"

int main()
{
    // Get actual time.
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    // Get the number of days since start of the year.
    auto ymd = date::year_month_day( date::floor<date::days>(now) );
    auto ymd_ref = date::year{ymd.year()}/1/1;
    int days = (date::sys_days{ymd} - date::sys_days{ymd_ref}).count();

    // Get the fractional number of seconds of the day.
    auto microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(now - date::floor<date::days>(now));
    double seconds_since_midnight = 1e-6*microseconds.count();

    // Get fractional day number.
    std::cout << "Fractional day of the year: " << days + seconds_since_midnight / 86400. << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the code working as expected? Then you may get better answers on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @MikeBorkland. How to use `date` and `chrono` to skip the two-step approach seems like a valid question for SO to me. Do I need to rephrase it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question (upvoted).

I think first we need to decide on what the right answer is.  There's your answer, and currently the only other answer is [Matteo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55368080/576911).  For demonstration purposes, I've modified both answers to substitute in a "fake now" so that we can compare apples to apples:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
auto now = date::sys_days{date::March/27/2019} + 0h +  32min + 22s + 123456us;
```

(approximately now at the time I'm writing this)

[Chiel's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55367898/576911) code gives:

```
Fractional day of the year: 85.0225
```

[Matteo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55368080/576911) code gives:

```
Fractional day of the year: 85.139978280740735
```

They are close, but not close enough to both be considered right.

[Matteo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55368080/576911) code works with "average years":

```
auto this_year = date::floor<date::years>(now);
```

The length of a `date::years` is 365.2425 days, which is exactly right if you average all civil years over a 400 year period.  And working with the average year length can be very useful, especially when dealing with systems that don't care about human made calendars (e.g. physics or biology).

I'm going to guess that because of the way [Chiel's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55367898/576911) code is written, he would prefer a result that refers more precisely to *this* specific year.  Therefore the code presented below is [Chiel's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55367898/576911)'s algorithm, resulting in exactly the same result, only slightly more efficient and concise.

```
// Get actual time.
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

// Get the number of days since start of the year.
auto sd = date::floor<date::days>(now);
auto ymd = date::year_month_day( sd );
auto ymd_ref = ymd.year()/1/1;
std::chrono::duration<double, date::days::period> days = sd - date::sys_days{ymd_ref};

// Get the fractional number of seconds of the day.
days += now - sd;

// Get fractional day number.
std::cout << "Fractional day of the year: " << days.count() << std::endl;
```

The first thing I noted was that `date::floor<date::days>(now)` was being computed in 3 places, so I'm computing it *once* and saving it in `sd`.

Next, since the final answer is a double-based representation of `days`, I'm going to let `<chrono>` do that work for me by storing the answer in a `duration<double, days>`.  Any time you find yourself converting units, it is better to let `<chrono>` do it for you.  It probably won't be faster.  But it definitely won't be slower, or wrong.

Now it is a simple matter to add the fractional day to the result:

```
days += now - sd;
```

using whatever precision `now` has (microseconds or whatever).  And the result is now simply `days.count()`.

**Update**

And with just a little bit more time to reflect ...

I noticed that with the simplified code above, one can more easily see the entire algorithm as a single expression.  That is (removing namespace qualification in order to get everything on one line):

```
duration<double, days::period> days = sd - sys_days{ymd_ref} + now - sd;
```

And this clearly algebraically simplifies down to:

```
duration<double, days::period> days = now - sys_days{ymd_ref};
```

In summary:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace date;

// Get actual time.
auto now = system_clock::now();

// Get the start of the year and subract it from now.
using ddays = duration<double, days::period>;
ddays fd = now - sys_days{year_month_day{floor<days>(now)}.year()/1/1};

// Get fractional day number.
std::cout << "Fractional day of the year: " << fd.count() << '\n';
```

In this case, letting `<chrono>` do the conversions for us, allowed the code to be sufficiently simplified such that the algorithm itself could be algebraically simplified, resulting in cleaner and more efficient code that is provably equivalent to the original algorithm in the OP's question.

### C++20 update

And in C++20 can be done entirely within `std::chrono`:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace chrono;

    // Get actual time.
    auto now = system_clock::now();

    // Get the start of the year and subract it from now.
    using ddays = duration<double, days::period>;
    ddays fd = now - sys_days{year_month_day{floor<days>(now)}.year()/1/1};

    // Get fractional day number.
    cout << "Fractional day of the year: " << fd << '\n';
}
```

[Demo.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bvJGFJzZlUoeGid2)

Comment: That name looks familiar, like the same name on the library I just got from github `:)`  Talk about a library with great support!

Comment: Wonderful. That is a significant reduction in lines of code and, even more important, in complexity.

Comment: I remember seeing elsewhere that you were not using `.count()` of a suitable `duration` to get the result, but you would divide whatever `duration` you have by `duration<double,days::period>{1}`. Does this have any advantage over `.count()`?

Comment: This was just carelessness on my part.  I copied it from the previous code.  `fd/days{1}` would have worked fine here to produce a `double`.  Instead just chose to print the duration.  The output is now suffixed by `d` (demo link updated).  Thank you for bringing this to my attention.